# Thunderbird confused about EPS attachments

Tags: macos, thunderbird

Sometimes, when I receive (Thunderbird 2.0.0.23 on OS X 10.5) emails with an EPS attachement sent from Mail OS X 10.4, I cannot open the EPS file. Thunderbird shows me 1 file, that can't be opened with any software but text edit.

But, if I forward the email to myself, the forwarded email then has 2 files of the same name. One of the 2 forwarded files can be opened as expected.

What can be wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the topmost line or two from one of the files opening in TextEdit?

Answer (score 0):

Try detaching the file before opening it.

Comment: Already tried it, to no avail.

Comment: Is this for a specific email account? Your provider (Gmail, Yahoo, ISP) might be messing with the attachment.

Comment: No, it is from our company's email address. It's hosted by 1und1, sending out of the office via the internet server back into the office.

Answer (score 0):

You could be losing OS X specific metadata when it's attached and send over e-mail. It's been a long time since I dealt with .eps files but I seem to recall we used to have to zip eps files before sending them for this reason. We've long since abandonded the format though. Anyway, it's worth a shot, having the file zipped before being e-mailed.